# Swift IOS - Change layout subviews

Tags: swift, layout, subview

I have an uiview and a button in it, also another uiview and a label. Both uiview with a button and uiview with a label added as a subview to self.

Now, when I change the frame of the self, respective subviews (uiview with a button & uiview with a label) frames to be adjusted and to fit based on the new frame set.

I tried to convert the co-ordinates of the subviews to newframe of the self, but that not works.

How do I work here, any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using autolayout, checkout layoutIfNeeded(). Hope this is helpful. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but am not using autolayout...any sample code to do this will be more helpful

Comment: It worked with func layoutsubviews()